# Postfix as a Send-Only SMTP Server on NGINX Server blocks - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, email, postfix, nginx

I have a question. Let me try to explain my question through an example:
NGINX Server Blocks in available three different live websites:

- Test-one.com
- Test-two.com
- Test-three.com

> Droplet name is also different: Test-Dad

**How should I install and configure Postfix as a Send-Only SMTP Server?**

Thank you!